# how to redirect to product edit tab from observer without saving product data

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

observer can't redirect to product edit page even product contain error message.my code is as below please review code and give me suggestion where is the problem.
i m calling catalog_product_save_before event in my observer.

```
$data['aproductid']   = $this->_getRequest()->getParam('id');
if(in_array($check,$resultarray))
            {
                 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('You have entered duplicate licence no');
                 Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('*/*/edit', array(
            'id'    => $data['aproductid'],
            '_current'=>true)));
                 return;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be, that the response is altered at the end of the observer.

You can try this:

```
$e = new Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Exception();
$e->prepareForward('edit');
throw $e;
```

Comment: Thanks Fabian for your valuable time to replay.i will  try your code. but i had found solution that is after redirect string call exit. it will take at edit page if error.

Comment: ya i know fabian but your code does not working in my situation.

Comment: dammit. :( But I know this problem. A widely used german extension does it the same way with a three line long comment :)